# Powershell: Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 'AsPlainText'

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell-2.0

Iam running following script in powershell. (its saved in temp.ps1 file)

```
[String]$ServiceAccountPassword ='Password'
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $ServiceAccountPassword –AsPlainText -Force
```

When I run it from powershell ISE it works fine.

But when call this script from c# application i.e.

```
_powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
var sr = new StreamReader(scriptFile);
_powerShell.AddScript(sr.ReadToEnd());
_powerShell.InvocationStateChanged += _powerShell_InvocationStateChanged;
var outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
_powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
IAsyncResult async =_powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null,     outputCollection, null, AsyncInvoke, null);
```

I am getting

***Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type     'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter     'AsPlainText'.***

Comment: is this how your ps1 file looks? does it has a param() section?

Comment: @Avshalom, sorry for late reply, no the original powershell takes the parameter. I have just posted the simplified version.    It  takes the following param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SomeKey,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$AnotherKey). And in c# code i pass this parameter as          _powerShell.AddParameter("SomeKey", "testValue");